# Map marker location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the following function with google maps API v3.

When a user drags and drop the map marker on a location then this location/address diplayed inside an input field.

How can i allow visitors typing their location inside this input field and then when they click on a button to move the marker to the desired location?

This is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();              
function geocodePosition(pos) {
geocoder.geocode({
latLng: pos
}, function(responses) {
if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
} else {
updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
}
});

}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
latLng.lat(),
latLng.lng()
].join(', ');
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
document.getElementById('address').value = str;
}

function initialize() {

 var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.02733457017991,-118.25942712402343);
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
 zoom:8,
 center: latLng,
 zoomControlOptions: {
 style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
 },
 mapTypeControl: false,
 streetViewControl: false,
 scrollwheel: false,
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
 });

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: latLng,
 title: 'Drag and Drop me anywhere',
 map: map,
 icon : 'markers/map_marker.png',
 draggable: true
 });



 updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
 geocodePosition(latLng);


 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
 updateMarkerAddress('Locating...');
 });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {

  updateMarkerPosition(marker.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {

  geocodePosition(marker.getPosition());
  });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);             
 </script>
```

and this is the html code:

```
<body>
<div id="mapCanvas"></div>
<div id="infoPanel">

<div class="row"><span class="label">Lat, Lon:</span>
<span id="info"></span></div>
<div class="row"><span class="label">Address:</span>
<input class="address-field" id="address"/>
<button class="button-locate" id="locate">Locate</button></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Use the [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) to geocode the address and place the marker when they click the button.

Comment: i did it and now works but after you click the button locate when you drag the marker doesnt update the location inside the input field. Also every time you click on Locate Button it adds one more marker. i want to use only one marker.

Comment: All of those are duplicate questions, have you searched for solutions yet?

Comment: @geocodezip i searched but didnt find a solution yet !

Answer (score 0):

```
 "results" : [
  {       
      "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224764,
               "lng" : -122.0842499
            },
   }
```

The result lat, lng of address Can you use this to set Location of marker, try this code;

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var marker;
function geocodePosition(pos) {
geocoder.geocode({
     address: $("#idOfInput").val(),
}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
          marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
          updateMarkerAddress(results[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
          updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
});

}
```